# Accessing property of MongoDB object in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb, object

Ultimately I'm attempting to access the `customer_id` property from the MongoDB object below.  I can do this by converting to an array first:

```
$manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");
$filter = [ "customer_id" => ['$eq' => '1001']];
$query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter);
$cursor = $manager->executeQuery('srp.products', $query);
$cursor = $cursor->toArray();
print_r ($cursor[0]->customer_id);
```

But I cannot access it by using:

```
$cursor->cursor['current_doc']->customer_id
```

Will I always need to convert to an array first, or am I missing something?

```html
MongoDB\Driver\Cursor Object
(
    [cursor] => Array
        (
            [stamp] => 0
            [is_command] => 
            [sent] => 1
            [done] => 
            [end_of_event] => 
            [in_exhaust] => 
            [has_fields] => 
            [query] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [find] => products
                    [filter] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [customer_id] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [$eq] => 1001
                                )

                        )

                )

            [fields] => stdClass Object
                (
                )

            [read_preference] => Array
                (
                    [mode] => 1
                    [tags] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [flags] => 0
            [skip] => 0
            [limit] => 0
            [count] => 1
            [batch_size] => 0
            [ns] => srp.products
            [current_doc] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [_id] => MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID Object
                        (
                            [oid] => 576aa3469771c4dbeef44022
                        )

                    [customer_id] => 1001
                    [products] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 150
                            [1] => 160
                            [2] => 170
                            [3] => 180
                        )

                )

        )

    [server_id] => 1
)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, you are supposed to either call `->toArray()` like you do or you can `foreach` through the `Cursor` to get results. For more informations on what's available in `Cursor` you can the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-driver-cursor.php).